# Azure Queue job stop running without any exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-queues

I have a job, which runs every 2minutes to check the queue and send queue messages to the 3rd party.
It stops running in the middle without generating any exception or logs information.
Other jobs within same worker role are running without any interruption.
When I restart worker role, it starts working.

I cannot figure out any issue except following exception in EventViewer 
[image]

Comment: Try to look under 'Application and Services Logs' --> 'Windows Azure'

Comment: Hard to know why without understanding how your code works and any logs that are outputted. Do you get any errors when you run this locally?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Is your Job set to Continuously run? Also, you may be interested in [this blog post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.V6trVvkrLRa)